# Why my ajax login form doesn't work correctly?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I create a login form using AJAX . 
And this is my JQUERY code:

```
$("#logbtn").on("click" , function() {
  if (!$("div").hasClass("error"))
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
    type:'post',
    url:'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/facecar/admin/inc/proccesslogin.php',
    data:{
     username: $("#loguser").val(),
     password: $("#logpass").val()
    },
    success:function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response == "yes")
      {
        alert("answer is yes ");
      } else {
        alert("answer is no !");
      }
    }
    });
  }
});
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  if (strpos($_POST["username"] , "moria") >= 0)
    {
      echo "yes";
    } else {
      echo "false";
    }
?>
```

I put the response in the console and it show my php codes and alert "answer is no !" . what is problem ?

Comment: What does you console.log(response); say?

Comment: And `console.log($("#loguser").val())` for that matter

Comment: Check for blank spaces before/after your opening/closing PHP tag (you don't need the closing one fyi). Nice login feature btw :)

Comment: I want to see the content of response . And i did it .

Comment: I don't understand your last statement.  Did you solve your problem @mortezajamali ?

Comment: Excuse me . i don't know English fully . Yes , i solved that .

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are using wordpress and the way you are trying ajax in wordpress is not the right way. In wordpress ajax url is `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`.
You'll get an idea from this link: [Ajax call from front in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169103/ajax-call-theme-functions-from-front). I hope you can do the rest following that link.

Let's make it easy for you to understand...

write in your functions.php

```
/* include your js script */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    //Change the key and url with yours
    wp_register_script('my-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my-js.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-js');

    //Localize script data to be used in my-js.js
    $scriptData = array();
    $scriptData['ajaxurl'] = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    $scriptData['action'] = 'answerAction';

    wp_localize_script( 'my-js', 'my_js_data', $scriptData );

}
/* Add your server code */
add_action("wp_ajax_answerAction", "answerAction");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_answerAction", "answerAction");
function answerAction(){
    if (strpos($_POST["username"] , "moria") >= 0)
    {
      echo "yes";
    } else {
      echo "false";
    }
    die();
}
```

Now, add you js script in my-js.js

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logbtn').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                'action': my_js_data.action,
                'username': jQuery("#loguser").val(),
                'password': jQuery("#logpass").val()
            };
            if (!$("div").hasClass("error"))
            {
                jQuery.post( my_js_data.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response == "yes")
                    {
                        alert("answer is yes ");
                    } else {
                        alert("answer is no !");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Best of luck.